# Как правильно базовому объекту присвоить конструктор наследника?

Tags: c++, ооп

Добрый день, пытаюсь разобраться с ООП в С++. Но возникла небольшая проблема.

Вот имею базовый класс `Base`:

```
class Base : public item {
public:
    Base();
    //Base* Create(ItemType t);
    virtual void Input();
    virtual void Print();
    ~Base();
protected:
    /* добавлено в Base */
    enum ItemType type;
    //struct List * DayRace;
    std::string PointOfDeparture;
    std::string Destination;
    int LengthOfTheRoute;
    int TimeOutput[2];
    int TimeIntput[2];
    int NumberOfSeatsAvailable;
};
```

А у `Base` есть 3-и наследуемых класса вида:

```
class Rail: public Base {
public:
    Rail();
    ~Rail();
};
```

Так вот, в классе `subjList` я пытаюсь создавать наследников таким образом:

```
class subjList {
protected:
    Base* p;
public:
    subjList();
    explicit subjList(ItemType t);
    ~subjList();
};


subjList::subjList(ItemType t) {

    switch (t) {
    case itAircraft:
        p = new Aircraft;
        break;
    case itRail:
        p = new Rail;
        break;
    case itBus:
        p = new Bus;
        break;
    }
    if (p) {
        this->type = t;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Но компилятор ругается ...

Можете мне подсказать, как правильно создавать наследуемые объекты в зависимости от того что захочет пользователь?

Comment: не `this->type = t;` a `p->type = t;` Как правило, много пользы бывает от описания ошибки компилятора вплоть до ее прямого цитирования :)

Comment: в строке "p = new Aircraft;"
Ошибка C2440 =: невозможно преобразовать "Aircraft *" в "Base *"

Comment: а еще в class Rail: public Base{
public:
    Rail();
    ~Rail();
}; 
 Серьезность Код Описание Проект Файл Строка Состояние подавления
Ошибка C2504 Base: не определен базовый класс

Comment: Сдаётся, что у вас при описании класса `Aircraft` недоступно описание класса `Base`. Проверьте все директивы `#include` и порядок объявления в иерархии классов.

Comment: спасибо... не углядел ;)